# Error in cordova android app with ConnectivityManager

Tags: cordova, android-connectivitymanager

Hi cordova and android masters) I new in "cordova development".
I built android app on cordova. My app can open files with use of com.megster.cordova.FileChooser plugin. But since august app has a error when selecting and open file (file storage in FS on android device). 
In logcat of AndroidStudio I have warnings:

```
2019-12-02 18:50:02.532 10395-10395/com.quaternity.offline W/cr_AwContents: WebView.destroy() called while WebView is still attached to window.
2019-12-02 18:50:02.617 10395-10395/com.quaternity.offline W/cr_AwContents: Application attempted to call on a destroyed WebView
    java.lang.Throwable
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.a(PG:355)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.r(PG:636)
        at aIE.loadingStateChanged(PG:135)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:328)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6253)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
2019-12-02 18:50:02.633 10395-10479/com.quaternity.offline E/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: callback not found for RELEASED message
```

I don't now what to do. I have changed version of cordova, of android platform and change others filechooser plugins, but it's not help.
Now my cordova version 8.1.2, android version 7.1.4. Do anyone had such problem?